# Bootstrap Jumbotron alignment within a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying for a while without success.

I have a row with two jumbotron in it, but I can't figure out how to make theme the same height. 
I guess that there is paddling issue from the bootstrapp css but I do not know how to overide it ..

here is how it looks: 
[image]

```
<div class="row">
{% if project.has_member_responses %}
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="jumbotron greenback">
      <h4>Welcome to the Project test "{{  project.name }}" Detail page</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="jumbotron greenback">
      <div class="inner-score">
        <h6>Team Score</h6>
        <h4>85</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the two jumbotron with the same height ?

Comment: You could set a min-height which may help you.

Comment: I guess the problem come from the paddling, since the left jumbotron has only 1 line, when the right one has two ..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to fix the height of the **jumbotron**

```
.jumbotron.greenback {
  height:200px;
}
```